# Monte Carlo Simulation for Multiple Entries in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, montecarlo

I've been working to create a Monte Carlo simulation that will run through each ID of my dataframe and yield their respective Means and Standard Deviations. I've been able to write the code to get it for any one ID, but not to iterate through the entire list of IDs in my dataframe. So I could write each line individually, but I need the code to iterate through any mutable list of IDs.

Here, I've tried to create a list of lists in which each set of Monte Carlo observations can be stored (and the mean and std could be taken from). I don't believe that will be the most efficient way of coding this, but it's what I know at this point. Is there anyway to run the Monte Carlo simulation on each of the IDs (without specifically calling each)? I need to be able to add and remove various IDs and corresponding data from the list.

This is a follow up on: [Utilizing Monte Carlo to Predict Revenue in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52173863/utilizing-monte-carlo-to-predict-revenue-in-python)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


ID = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
Revenue = [1000, 1200, 1300, 100 ,500, 0, 800, 950, 4321, 800, 1000, 1200, 1300, 100 ,500, 0, 800, 950, 4321, 800]
odds = [0.5, 0.6, 0.33, 0.1, 0.9, 0.87, 0.37, 0.55, 0.97, 0.09, 0.5, 0.6, 0.33, 0.1, 0.9, 0.87, 0.37, 0.55, 0.97, 0.09]

d = {'ID': ID, 'Revenue': Revenue, 'Odds': odds}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['Expected Value'] = df['Revenue']*df['Odds']

print(df)

num_samples = 100
df['Random Number'] = np.random.rand(len(df))

def monte_carlo_array(df):
    for _ in range(len(df)):
        yield []

mc_arrays = list(monte_carlo_array(df))

# Fill each list with 100 observations (no filtering necessary)
id_1 = []
filter_1 = (df['ID'] == 5)

for _ in range(num_samples):
    sample = df['Revenue'] * np.where(np.random.rand(len(df)) < \
                          df['Odds'], 1, 0)
    for l in monte_carlo_array(df):
        for i in l:
        mc_arrays[i].append(sample.sum())
    id_1.append(sample.loc[filter_1].sum())


# Plot simulation results.
n_bins = 10
plt.hist([id_1], bins=n_bins, label=["ID: 1"])
plt.legend()
plt.title("{} simulations of revenue".format(num_samples))

print(mc_arrays)

df['Monte Carlo Mean'] = np.mean(mc_arrays[0])
print(df['Monte Carlo Mean'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, this is what you're going for:

- For each row (which represents an `ID`), you want a total of `num_samples` Monte Carlo simulations of whether that row achieves its `Revenue`.
- The way you determine whether a given simulated instance achieves its `Revenue` is by comparing a randomly drawn value in `[0,1]` against the `Odds` for that row (in standard Monte Carlo fashion).
- You want to know the mean and standard deviation of the `Revenue` for each row, across all samples.

If so, you can do this by leveraging the sampling function of the Binomial distribution, instead of drawing from a Uniform and then filtering based on `Odds`.  I'll post a solution using this approach at the end of this answer.

But since you've started out with the Uniform-draw approach: I'd recommend first making a sampling matrix `s_draws` of `n_rows = len(df)` by `num_samples` (aka `n_draws` in my code below).  Then apply the `Odds` check against all of the samples in each row of `s_draws`.  Then multiply by `Revenue`, and take the mean and sd for each row.  Like this:

First, draw the sampling matrix:

```
np.random.seed(42)

n_rows = len(df)
n_draws = 5
s_draws = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(n_rows, n_draws))

# the matrix of random values between [0,1]
# note: only showing the first 3 rows for brevity
s_draws
           0         1         2         3         4
0   0.374540  0.950714  0.731994  0.598658  0.156019
1   0.155995  0.058084  0.866176  0.601115  0.708073
2   0.020584  0.969910  0.832443  0.212339  0.181825
...
```

Now figure out which sampled instances "achieved" the target `Revenue`:

```
s_rev = s_draws.apply(lambda col: col.lt(df.Odds) * df.Revenue)

# the matrix of sampled revenue
s_rev
       0     1     2     3     4
0   1000     0     0     0  1000
1   1200  1200     0     0     0
2   1300     0     0  1300  1300
...
```

Finally, compute summary statistics for each row/`ID`:

```
s_result = pd.DataFrame({"avg": s_rev.mean(axis=1), "sd": s_rev.std(axis=1)})

# the summary statistics of each row of samples
s_result
       avg          sd
0    400.0  547.722558
1    480.0  657.267069
2    780.0  712.039325
...
```

And here's the version using Binomial sampling:

```
draws = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.binomial(n=1, p=df.Odds, size=(n_draws, n_rows)).T
).multiply(df.Revenue, axis=0)

pd.DataFrame({"avg": draws.mean(axis=1), "sd": draws.std(axis=1)})
```

Note: This all would work a little differently if `ID` was repeated across multiple rows in `df`.  In that case, you could use `groupby` and then take the summary statistics.  But in your example, `ID` is never repeated, so I'll leave the answer as-is for now.

Comment: The Uniform-draw approach that you utilized makes perfect sense to me and works well when I applied it to my code. s_result is yielding exactly what I'm looking for. 
I'm still a little confused with the Binomial sampling component though. The line: `pd.DataFrame({"avg": draws.mean(axis=0), "sd": draws.std(axis=0)})` is returning a dataframe that is n_draws long. If this version of the code is more efficient, I'd like to find a way to use it (or at least learn it for the future).

Comment: Whoops, sorry, the arguments in `mean` and `std` should be `axis=1`.  Good catch!  The Binomial approach just captures the intuition behind comparing the random draws against `Odds` - that's basically what a Binomial random variable is.  Either approach should yield the same results.